# Let $P ⊆ X ×Y$. Does $π_1(P)×π_2(P) = P$? Give a proof or a counterexample.

Tags: calculus, proof-writing, projection

Proofs and fundamentals, exercise 4.2.5. I need your help, maybe it's false.
Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets, let $A ⊆ X$ and $B ⊆ Y$ be subsets and let $π_1 : X × Y → X$ and $π_2 : X × Y → Y$ be projection maps.
c) Let $P ⊆ X × Y$. Does $π_1(P)×π_2(P) = P$? Give a proof or a counterexample.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you leaning towards believing it's true, or false, and why?

Comment: Draw a picture and play with some sets. Can you think of a "thin" set whose projections cover $X$ and $Y$ completely?

Comment: One possible counterexample: a circle.

Comment: user642721 P= circle of ratio=1?

Comment: @JeanPaul Try a continuous example. As long as your figure is not a rectangle that is parallel to axises, you will get a counterexample. radius and/or center are irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you user642721 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Note that $\pi_1(P) \times \pi_2(P)$ contains *all possible combinations* $(x, y)$ with $x \in \pi_1(P)$ and $y \in \pi_2(P)$.

Work an example with $P$ as a couple of elements in your favorite product of sets, computing the projections and their Cartesian product and you'll see what I'm getting at.